# Hazelcast stops persisting to DB after sometime in write-behind mode

Tags: caching, persistence, hazelcast

We have a hazelcast cluster that works for sometime and it stops persisting data to DB when a brust of Put request is performed on the cache. Cache never recovers after this, in order for us to get the persistence going we had to bounce all our cluster instances one at a time. When they all bounced we see persistence continuing. We don't see any exceptions or anything on the store itself.. we are using 3.5 version. Any help is appreciated.